# How can i split an array containing URLs into groups?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing lots of urls to a few different sites. Is there a way to automatically split them

For example, Turn this:

```
http://url-one.com/page1.html
http://url-one.com/page3.html
http://url-one.com/page5.html
http://url-two.com/file/test.rar
http://url-two.com/file/test22.rar
http://url-two.com/file/test33.rar
http://url-three.net/pages/download/file/1
http://url-three.net/pages/download/file/2
http://url-three.net/pages/download/file/2
```

Into this:

```
url-one.com links:
http://url-one.com/page1.html
http://url-one.com/page3.html
http://url-one.com/page5.html

url-two.com links:
http://url-two.com/file/test.rar
http://url-two.com/file/test22.rar
http://url-two.com/file/test33.rar

url-three.net links:
http://url-three.net/pages/download/file/1
http://url-three.net/pages/download/file/2
http://url-three.net/pages/download/file/2
```

I don't always know what the hosts are so i can't manually type the host to match it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$urlList[] = 'http://url-one.com/page1.html';
$urlList[] = 'http://url-two.com/file/test.rar';
$urlList[] = 'http://url-two.com/file/test.rar';
$urlList[] = 'http://url-two.com/file/test22.rar';
$urlList[] = 'http://url-three.net/pages/download/file/1';

$groupedList = array();

foreach($urlList as $url){
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    $groupedList[$parse['host']][] = $url;
}

foreach($groupedList as $group){
    echo "<div>\n";
        foreach($group as $url){
            echo $url."<br>\n";
        }
    echo "</div>\n";
}

/* Output:
<div>
http://url-one.com/page1.html<br>
</div>
<div>
http://url-two.com/file/test.rar<br>
http://url-two.com/file/test.rar<br>
http://url-two.com/file/test22.rar<br>
</div>
<div>
http://url-three.net/pages/download/file/1<br>
</div>
*/
```

Edit: Per comment request, a way to filter domains out. Since I was storing the hosts as the key, I used `array_diff_key` and `array_flip`. PHP 5.6 added a way to pass the key to `array_filter` which would have made things easier as well.

```
$filterDomainList[] = 'url-one.com';
$filterDomainList[] = 'url-three.net';

$filtered = array_diff_key( $groupedList, array_flip( $filterDomainList ) );
var_dump($filtered);

/*array(1) {
  ["url-two.com"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(32) "http://url-two.com/file/test.rar"
    [1]=>
    string(32) "http://url-two.com/file/test.rar"
    [2]=>
    string(34) "http://url-two.com/file/test22.rar"
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to mention i don't always know the urls. Will i need to know all the URLs for this to work?

Comment: I guess it depends how you want to display them, one sec, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I wanted to post something similar. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php -- this is the function to go.

Comment: Is there a way to show the host so i can all of 1 host links inside 1 div, then all another host links in another div?

Comment: Thanks this is awesome. 1 more thing. Is it possible to remove URLs from the array based on the host? Not sure if this is a separate question, Theres some hosts i don't want to show but don't know the full URLs only the host. Is this possible?

Comment: Will i need to know the full URL for this? As i only know the host part that i want to remove.

Comment: No, you shouldn't. You only need to know the list of URLs (hosts specifically) that you want to filter out. I can update the answer in a bit with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array while checking whether each item in array starts with certain string (like "http://url-three.net/") and based on that add this item to certain array

```
foreach($urls as $url){
    if ( strpos($url, "http://url-one.net") > 0)
        ; // add to 1st array
    else if ( strpos($url, "http://url-two.net") > 0)
        ; // add to 2nd array
    else if ( strpos($url, "http://url-three.net") > 0)
        ; // add to 3rd array
}
```